# Feeder line to sub panel running parallel along/ through a load bearing wall w/header

Tags: electrical, wiring, framing

I am planning a new feeder line from 200A exterior breaker to 125A interior sub panel. My preferred route runs ~25’ along/parallel through a load bearing wall where I want to widen a door opening by a few feet. This wall is also supporting a stairwell. I’m trying to determine the most efficient and safest method for running the wires or cable through the studs and header to the subpanel.

Comment: Is the wall completely open or is it covered with drywall and you're trying to minimize damage? What's above & below this wall? What about the floor/ceiling? If you'll [edit] your question to include some pictures and/or drawings to help people better understand the situation, they'll be able to give you better answers. Unfortunately, though, there's probably no "best" solution, which is why asking what's "best" leads to questions being closed as opinion-based. If you'll indicate in your pics/drawings what you're thinking about doing, folks will be able to approve or point out potential issues

Comment: Load bearing walls can only have holes of about 40%(around 1.5 inch in 2x4s).  Structural changes(widening a doorway) in load bearing walls should have an engineer check/design them.   Probably going under or over the wall be best, should only add a few feet because of the doorway anyway.

Comment: @crip659 has a _great_ point! Widening a door in a load bearing wall _does_ need an SE to look over the plan, _especially_ if the wall also supports stairs!

Comment: Will also need to check if you can pump 200 amps to 125 amp breaker, I know it works the other way 125 to 200.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. This is a basement room so floor joist are above. I peeled the wall so it’s exposed. I’ll run my line through the joist bays instead. I will step down to 125A with breaker at the external box. 

So this brings up feeder line type and conduit need. Other posts suggest I use al#1 or copper 2/0. Can I use the coated cable if the clearance in joist bays is adequate? I’ll get some pics when I’m back at job site.

Comment: @crip659 with a subpanel feeder it doesn't matter if the main panel can support 125A load.  You need to do a NEC Article 220 Load Calc on the subpanel to assure it is < the wire size (115A for #2Cu or 120A for #0Al).... then another one on *the whole house* to assure it is <200A.  It's only limited to 200A minus the subpanel load calc.  Since 115A and 120A wires are not made, the round-up rule allows 125A breakers but the sub load calc can't exceed wire size.

Comment: Your feeder wires will depend on the breaker they come from, not the breaker they feed.

Comment: The whole house is running on a 70A breaker feeding off the 200A main at the moment. I calculated the house load at about 100 but can work that number up again

Comment: What loads is this subpanel supporting?